# AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'screen_width'

Tags: python, class, pygame

I have been trying to build a alien invasion game but when I run it it gives me the following: "AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'screen_width'"

I understand what the error means but I cannot understand why I am getting it. I have double checked my spelling, even tried changing the names in my Settings class and the Alien Invasion class to no success. Does someone know what might have went wrong? Thanks

```py
class AlienInvasion:
    
    # Initialize the game and create game resources
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.ai_settings = Settings()

        #this code below creates the pygame screen. The set_caption method just changes th title of the window
        #remmeber that if we do not pass the attibutes (screen, etc), it is considered the default value and will not change until we change it via another method in the class
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.ai_settings.screen_width, self.ai_settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")


    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            #create the background color
            self.screen.fill(self.ai_settings.bg_color)
            pygame.display.flip()

    `if __name__ == '__main__':
        ai = AlienInvasion()
        ai.run_game()

class Settings:
    """A class to store all settings for the Alien Invasions game."""

    def __init__(self):
        #Screen Settings
        self.screen_width= 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230,230,230)
```

Comment: Both classes are in separate files, I just did not know how to illustrate that in the questions box and Settings is not used anywhere in my Alien_Invasion Directory except in settings.py

Comment: I do not, I even tried changing the class name from 'Settings' to 'Set' and I get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know but after some formatting its working fine by me.

```
import pygame
import sys


class Settings:
"""A class to store all settings for the Alien Invasions game."""

def __init__(self):
    # Screen Settings
    self.screen_width = 200
    self.screen_height = 200
    self.bg_color = (0, 230, 230)


class AlienInvasion:

# Initialize the game and create game resources
def __init__(self):
    pygame.init()
    self.ai_settings = Settings()

    # this code below creates the pygame screen. The set_caption method just changes th title of the window
    # remmeber that if we do not pass the attibutes (screen, etc), it is considered the default value and will not change until we change it via another method in the class
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.ai_settings.screen_width, self.ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

def run_game(self):
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        # create the background color
        self.screen.fill(self.ai_settings.bg_color)
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

Comment: It works! Like you said, it was formatting. I didn't indent the __init__ method. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The settings were stored in a settings.py file and set using the init method of a class Settings:

```
class Settings:
"""A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's settings."""
        # Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
```

I had forgotten the indents in this method, hence the self.* lines were not considered and not available in the alien_invasion class in the other file.